# dnsmasq ignores queries from non local network

Tags: dnsmasq

I've configured a dnsmasq service into my servers network. I can query it correctly from local server and "brothers" servers in the network.

```
root@yyy ~# nslookup google.com 172.25.x.xxx
Server:     172.25.x.xxx
Address:    172.25.x.xxx#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.210.174
```

However when I try to query it from my dev machine (range 172.144.x.x) I get no response. Ports are correctly open (tested with nmap and telnet).

```
$ nmap -p 53 172.25.x.xxx -Pn

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-04-12 17:54 CEST
Nmap scan report for 172.25.x.xxx
Host is up (0.0018s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds

$ nslookup google.com 172.25.x.xxx
connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

It seems like the flag --local-service is enabled however I've set interface and listen-address variables

```
interface=eth0
listen-address=127.0.0.1,172.25.x.xxx
```

I've saw that --local-service is enabled by default but not when using "interface" and "listen-address". Is there any way to check in is still active?

**edit**
Seems it could be a udp/tcp related issue. This query works from my dev network

```
$ dig +tcp +short cnn.com @172.25.7.110
151.101.129.67
151.101.193.67
```

It seems strange because dev and server machines can "talk" udp. (tested with "netcat -u -l -p 53" on server and "netcat -u 172.25.x.xxx 53" on dev machine)

Answer (score 0):

The firewall rules is the culprit it seems. Check the `nmap` list: `53/tcp`. Make sure UDP is allowed as well.

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed [this way](https://superuser.com/questions/1255211/dnsmasq-not-answering-dns-queries-from-routed-subnet#comment2292584_1258775): Edit the `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq` and remove `--local-service` from `DNSMASQ_OPTS` variable to fix it.